How can I find the latest date where a particular query returns no rows in a table?
I have a SQL query:
select max(date) 
    from index_constituents 
    where (opening_closing ='O' 
        and index_code ='buk350n' 
        and issuer = 'cboe') and date = '2024-04-25';




id
date
issuer
index_code
opening_closing




1393
2024-04-25
cboe
buk350n
O


1394
2024-04-25
cboe
buk350n
O



When I run the same query but for the day before, I get:
```sql
select max(date) 
    from index_constituents 
    where (opening_closing ='O' 
        and index_code ='buk350n' 
        and issuer = 'cboe') and date = '2024-04-24';
```

 id    |   date        |  issuer |  index_code   | opening_closing
 -     |  -            | -       | -             | -
1402   |   2024-04-24  |   cboe  |   buk350n     |   O

When I run
```sql
select max(date) 
    from index_constituents 
    where (opening_closing ='O' 
        and index_code ='buk350n' 
        and issuer = 'cboe') and date = '2024-04-23';
```

NOTHING IS RETURNED.
So I want to return 2024-04-23
i.e. I want to find the most recent date BEFORE A GIVEN DATE where there is no data when I run my query

Please mention what you expect from the sample data ? @user21641220

It seems that you want *select max(date) from index_constituents where opening_closing <> 'O' and index_code <> 'buk350n' and issuer <> 'cboe'; *. If not please clarify the question,  what do you mean by I am trying to find the latest date where no rows are returned. Add some data example and expected result

Sorry maybe it was redundant to include sample data - I was just trying to show what the table looks like.

@ErgestBasha I am trying to find the max(date), where when I run the query select * from index_constituents where (opening_closing ='O' and index_code ='buk350n' and issuer = 'cboe')  -> returns no rows

@ErgestBasha When I run the query you proposed it returns [NULL]

You're gonna have to excuse me here but, if you want the latest date where no rows are returned. Don't you just take the max(date) + 1 and add 1 day to it? Am I missing something here?

@TeunKruijer I still get [NULL] when I try max(date) + 1

@user21641220 I don't  understand the logic. Based on your given example what should be the expected result and why ?

What is the max ago of your brother that was born more than a hundred years ago? What is the max ago of your pet born after 2100-04-01? None, those don’t exist.

Apologies my friend my fault, I meant the max(date) before today's date - appreciate I didn't have this in my question initially, but added now!

@user21641220 describe logic behind your problem ?

Your are continuously changing your requirements without proper description...

@user21641220 Either your query should find the latest date and you add one day to it or the date is null and you should just return the current_date. SELECT COALESCE(MAX(date) + INTERVAL '1 day', CURRENT_DATE) AS next_date

@JonasMetzler yes! the query that returns 2024-04-23 is what I am after. Thank you very much! I think the .idate should read .date, but when I change this it works :))
Thank you again sir

Apologies all, I have tried to make it as clear as possible now**

Note: You have edited the question extremely often and switch from one use case to the next. Therefore, people can't help you. I deleted my answer that was correct for your original description and voted to close the question.

You haven't found the answer after 30+ comments?

Nope... it might be how I described it, but I can't make it any clearer than it currently is in the question..

I just want to write a query with some condition, e.g. select * from index_constituents where code='buk350n'and a given date (e.g. 2024-01-01), and I want the query to return the most recent date before this given date (2024-01-01) where NO DATA is returned for the query.
But I want this date to be something a user can insert, becuase I want to run this query against many dates**

If you need to find latest date with no record after existing record's date then you can use 1st query:
select 
"date"-1 latest_unfound_record
from 
(
select 
"date" - LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY date desc) date_difference_in_days,
* 
from index_constituents
) as temp
where date_difference_in_days>1
order by date desc
LIMIT 1;

If you need to find latest date before today with no records then use this second query:
select 
next_date-1 latest
from 
(
select 
"date" - COALESCE (LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), CURRENT_DATE) date_difference_in_days,
COALESCE (LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), CURRENT_DATE) AS next_date , 
* 
from index_constituents where date <= CURRENT_DATE
) as temp
where date_difference_in_days<-1
order by date desc
LIMIT 1;


for the second solution above, how can I add my conditions like where (opening_closing ='O'  and index_code ='buk350n'  and issuer = 'cboe') and date = '2024-04-23';

Actual question have been edited multiple times. for your latest requirement, please replace "CURRENT_DATE" with your custom date you want the data before.

Replace current date keyword with '2024-04-23' and add (opening_closing ='O'  and index_code ='buk350n'  and issuer = 'cboe') inside sub query which i have named as temp.

Run this query:
(select
next_date-1 latest
from
(
select
"date" - COALESCE (LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), '2024-04-24') date_difference_in_days,
COALESCE (LEAD(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), '2024-04-24') AS next_date ,
*
from index_constituents
where date <= '2024-04-24' and (opening_closing ='O'  and index_code ='buk350n'  and issuer = 'cboe')
) as temp
where date_difference_in_days<-1
order by date desc
LIMIT 1;)

with dates as (
    select date, date - lag(date, 1, date - 2) over (order by date) as gap
    from index_constituents 
    where opening_closing = 'O' and index_code = 'buk350n' and issuer = 'cboe'
    -- and date <= <start date> -- if you want to begin the search on a specific date
    group by date
)
select max(date) - 1 as GapDate
from dates
where gap > 1;

...
-- if a gap is possible where the search start date is past all available data
select
    case when <start date> - max(date) > 1
              -- or max(date) is null -- search had no results
         then <start date> - 1
         else max(case when gap > 1 then date end) - 1 end as GapDateV2
from dates;

...
-- alternately, append the search date to create the anchor/bookend
with dates as (
    select date, date - lag(date, 1, date - 2) over (order by date) as gap
    from (select date from index_constituents union all select '2024-04-25'::date) t
    where date <= '2024-04-25'
    group by date
)
select
    max(case when gap > 1 then date end) - 1 as gap
from dates;

I've realized it does make more sense to use lead() here rather than lag(). I'll have to return later to update this answer.
This gets a list of distinct dates where the criteria are met. Each date is compared to the next earliest on the list to compute the gap starting with whatever is the latest date found. You want to find the day before the latest date where there's a gap larger than one.
If no such gap exists within the data it will be treated as occurring on the day before the earliest date found. If there are no rows meeting the criteria at all then no date is returned either. I believe these date operations are valid for the date type but it might not work some for related Postgres types without minor tweaking of the conversions/calculations.
Important: OP is specifically interested in supplying a date (current date, apparently) where the search should begin looking backward. It seems to be assumed that there will always be some data present to represent that start date such that it can be an anchor for using lag(). I'm not confident that is reliable.
Suppose that the relevant data is filtered with the condition date <= 2024-04-25 but that there is no data available for yesterday (24th) nor today (25th) while data for the 23rd is present. (Example) The naive logic using just lag() won't discover this void on the 24th because it need dates from both sides to define the span. To address that the second query has logic to allow for a date past the maximum range of data present.
As these kinds of queries can potentially cover a lot of historical data it's good to be careful about applying appropriate criteria to narrow and limit the search space as much as possible.

Thanks @shawnt00, is it possible to generalise this to insert a particular date?
So that it looks back for the most recent before before this date where there is no data?
Apologies, I realised only now that I want a particular date, rather than today's date.

@user21641220 I've answered the question as it was described. I'm not clear what you mean by "insert" or what you mean by "this date".

Thanks Shawnt, when I run your query, the last from errors out with syntax error

Was it because of the comma? This query seems to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/lKnwWoNx

yepp query runs now, but it still doesn't give me the right anwer. Let' say I want to find the latest date that is before '2024-04-21' where there is no data (on '2024-04-20 there is no data in my database), can I just add date < 2024-04-21 to you query above? When I do this, the query returns '2024-04-14', which is in fact the next date after 2024-04-20 where there is no data. So it seems to skip one day where there is no data

If you use a less than or equal to 4/21 then the query will work. Since you haven't described exactly how your data works it difficult to anticipate your needs.

It's working properly. May be you're confusing about columns data type or values:
CREATE TABLE index_constituents (id int, date date, issuer varchar(10),
  index_code varchar(255), opening_closing varchar(20));

INSERT INTO index_constituents VALUES
  (1393, '2024-04-25', 'cboe', 'buk350n', 'O'),
  (1394, '2024-04-25', 'cboe', 'buk350n', 'O'),
  (1395, '2024-03-25', 'cboe', 'buk350n', 'O'),
  (1402, '2024-04-24', 'cboe', 'buk350n', 'O');

select max(date)
    from index_constituents 
    where (opening_closing = 'O'
        and index_code ='buk350n' 
        and issuer = 'cboe'); 

For check output :

Previous Data: https://dbfiddle.uk/8FNVcK-l 

Latest Changes: https://dbfiddle.uk/-rdlGxqO 


Please check your column date & opening_closing data_type.
date column maybe varchar and opening_closing may be boolean.
Please check the table description:
SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE table_name = 'index_constituents';


Ahh sorry! I meant a date that is before today's date

What you expect as a result ? @user21641220

Sorry, let me add some more sample data to my question

sure ... or create a db<>fiddle link and share it @user21641220

Best you change the column name date to some other name. Because it's a sql keyword. Rename your column at final output script in you working project.

I have updated my sample data and question - hope it makes it clearer* if not pleasde elt me know

One second, your answer isn't correct, for your latest sample data, I expect the max(date) to return 2024-04-23

Yes, what is your data type of columns date & opening_closing ?
